# SQL join changing counts

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
visit_id    event_list    seq_num    search_term
    1        search          1         sample
    1        click           3         null
    2        search          1         sample
    3        search          1         sample
    3        click           2         null
```

at the end of the day, I want

```
search_term    searches    visits    product_clicks
sample             3         3             1
```

keep in mind that it's only a click if it comes directly after the search.

Right now, I can get visits and searches correct, until I add in product clicks. I'm joining back on the table with a table of only click, then I join on `visit_id`. When I do this join, my searches jump up a ton and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code

```
select a.search_term
,count(a.visit_id) AS searches
,count(distinct a.visit_id) visits
,count(case when cast(b.seq_num as int) = cast(a.seq_num as int) + 1 then a.visit_id end) prod_click
from Table a join (select visit_id
                    ,seq_num
                    ,event_list
                    from Table
                    where event_list = 'click'
                    and seq_num != 'null') b
                    on b.visit_id = a.visit_id
where event_list = 'search'
group by 1
```

EDIT:
the query

```
select a.search_term
,count(distinct a.visit_id) as visits
,count(distinct case when a.search_term != 'null' then a.visit_id end) as searches
,count(distinct case when b.seq_num = a.seq_num + 1 then 1 end) as prod_click
from T a, T b
```

works for what I want, but the tables I'm working with are massive and this won't work. Does anyone have a way to make this better?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "case when" in your second line of code

```
count(distinct case when event_list = "click" then a.visit_id else 0) AS product_clicks,
count(distinct case when event_list = "searches" then a.visit_id else 0) AS searches,
```

you won't need to join the table I guess. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the table to reflect the table better - I made it ideal when in reality it doesn't work that way - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function* to make it.

`SUM` with `CASE WHEN`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  visit_id int,
  event_list varchar(50),
  seq_num int,
  search_term varchar(50)
);



insert into t values (1,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (1,'click',2,'sample');
insert into t values (2,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (3,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (3,'click',2,'sample');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select search_term,
       COUNT(distinct visit_id) searches,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_list = 'search' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) visits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_list = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) product_clicks
FROM T
GROUP BY search_term
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b193/24/0)**:

```
| search_term | searches | visits | product_clicks |
|-------------|----------|--------|----------------|
|      sample |        3 |      3 |              2 |
```

**EDIT**

You can try to use `LEAD` function to next status and compare the `seq_num`  is continuous by `ROW_NUMBER`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  visit_id int,
  event_list varchar(50),
  seq_num int,
  search_term varchar(50)
);



insert into t values (1,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (1,'click', 3,null);
insert into t values (2,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (3,'search',1,'sample');
insert into t values (3,'click', 2,null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by visit_id) - seq_num) rn
  FROM T
), cte1 as (
  select *,LEAD(event_list) OVER(PARTITION BY visit_id,rn order by visit_id) nextEvent 
  from cte 
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT search_term,       
         COUNT(distinct visit_id) searches,
         SUM(CASE WHEN event_list = 'search' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) visits,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN event_list = 'search' and nextEvent = 'click' then 1 end) product_clicks
  FROM cte1 
  group by search_term
)t
where search_term is not null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b193/24/0)**:

```
| search_term | searches | visits | product_clicks |
|-------------|----------|--------|----------------|
|      sample |        3 |      3 |              1 |
```

Comment: This is a great idea - but it doesn't work in practice. I updated the table because I had filled it in wrong. Basically, the click only counts if it is the next sequence after the search, and the clicks do not have a search term associated to them, just a visit id.

Comment: I am not sure what's the `product_clicks ` column logic? could you give me more detail?

Comment: product_clicks counts the number of times a click happens directly after a search. If the click is say request 3 and the search was request 1, we don't count that as a product_click. We want to connect product_clicks with a search.

Comment: What's your dbms? and the request col number is in `seq_num`?

Comment: If i understand your question, seq_num is just the request number.

Comment: So in this case `product_clicks=1`,because `Seq_num` is continuous in   `visit_id  =3` . Am I understand correct?